# Method count per class in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there an easy way to obtain this number, without scrolling each file in Eclipse (using PyDev or an additional plugin)? I am separating my code into functional/smaller classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can do this in Python itself without needing to consult an IDE, using the `inspect` module (part of the standard library).

```
import inspect

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        pass

# exclude __...__ methods
actual_methods = [member for member in inspect.getmembers(MyClass)
                  if not member[0].startswith('__')]
print(len(actual_methods))
```

Result:

```
2
```

Comment: Excellent! It is good enough to check things faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into PyDev to do that, but you could use the scripting functionality:

http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html

To get the classes/methods, it'd be something as:

```
from org.python.pydev.parser.fastparser import FastDefinitionsParser
from org.python.pydev.parser.visitors.scope.EasyASTIteratorVisitor import EasyASTIteratorVisitor

ps = edit.createPySelection()
contents = ps.getDoc().get()

ast = FastDefinitionsParser.parse(contents)
visitor = EasyASTIteratorVisitor()
ast.accept(visitor)
nodes = visitor.getClassesAndMethodsList()
```

That should give you the classes/methods from inside PyDev (then you can do the logic you need from inspecting the nodes -- which in this case will provide you with the classes/methods/attributes).

The scripting reference should give you details on how to bind the code to an action (note that it'll run in the internal PyDev Jython interpreter which is currently in version 2.2.1).